# Installing update site with feature renamed

Tags: eclipse, update-site

We have update site which contains feature X. User have installed the update site and now contain feature X.
Now due to naming conflicts of feature X, we have to rename it to feature Y. Now if the same user tries to install using the same Update Site, they get conflict as to only one of the feature X or Y can be installed.

Right now the work around is to uninstall old feature X and then use the update site or publish a new update site altogether. As our Users are dumb-users without the understanding of update sites/features etc, both these workaround doesn't do the job.

Is there a way to specify in feature.xml or site.xml or any othe file, that we can mark the new feature is just the renamed version of old feature and disable old one and install new one.

Note: All plugins in the new feature are same as old ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize the update descriptor of your feature IU. This can be done with a p2.inf next to your feature.xml file. According to this [p2 wiki page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Customizing_Metadata#Update_descriptor_advice%3a), the p2.inf file needs to contain something like this:

```
update.id = <feature.x.id>.feature.group
update.range = [0.0.0,<last feature x version>]
update.severity = 1
```